# Destructing a global array of List struct

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, linked-list, destructor

I was trying to destruct a global array of structs.
However, it creates following message and crashes in Visual Studio 2013.
(g++ does not crash). What causes this problem?

message:

> "DEBUG ASSERTION FAILED" _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

Here is the List struct:

```
template <typename T>
struct List {
    struct ListNode {
        ListNode() : item(0), next(0) {}
        ListNode(T x) : item(x), next(0) {}
        T item;
        ListNode* next;
    };
    T operator[](int idx);
    void insert(T x);
    T get(int idx);
    void print();
    List() : head(0),tail(0),size(0) {}
    ListNode* head;
    ListNode* tail;
    int size;

    ~List() {
        ListNode* h = head;
        while(h) {
            ListNode* n = h->next;
            delete h;
            h = n;
        }
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        size = 0;
    }

};
```

List::insert()

```
template <typename T>
void List<T>::insert(T x) {
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = new ListNode(x);
        tail = head;
    } else {
        tail->next = new ListNode(x);
        tail = tail->next;
    }
    size++;
}
```

Definition of the globa array:

```
List<int> a[1001];
```

Here is my code to destruct the global array of List structs:

```
loop(i,0,N+1) {
    delete &a[i];
}
```

Comment: why are you destroying elements of an array manually? It'll automatically be destroyed at the end of its scope...

Comment: I declared it as a `global variable` and I want to utilize memory as much as I can while running the program. (Precisely, I have number of test cases which consumes memory before terminating the program.)

Comment: consider adding a `clear()` method to remove elements in the lists then, or don't use a global

Comment: What is the point of using function`clear()`? Isn't it identical to call a destructor?

Comment: functionally yes, it would be, but `delete` is only for things allocated with `new`

Comment: Then, what's the difference? I don't quite understand why you suggested separate function. As you can see in `insert()`, every ListNode is allocated with `new` keyword.

Comment: Nothing on heap ...no use of 'new' in your code ..what are you trying to delete ?

Comment: because calling `.clear()` on each list *would not invoke undefined behavior*, you aren't allowed to `delete` on something not created with `new`, it is flat out wrong

Comment: Why don't you use smart pointers ?Will help you not to think about garbage collection

Comment: Now I see that I am trying to delete something is not on the heap. Thank you for all your advices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List<int> a[1001]` would not store in the heap if you're not using `new`.

Then you're trying to delete it, it raises memory corruption error, which is one of the possible reasons to get this error.

> DEBUG ASSERTION FAILED" _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

Solution: Use `new`